# python flask render_template and return csv/excel to browser

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am creating a flask app that takes a CSV as input. Parses the CSV and the content. Then returns an updated CSV to the browser to download/or instantly downloads. The program needs an HTML template for users to interact. I am attempting to use the render_template() method to return the HTML file and the CSV file via flask. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
        if request.method == "POST":
    print("POST request received!")

    if "file" not in request.files:
        return redirect(request.url)

    list_keywords = request.files["file"]
    if not list_keywords:
        return "No file"
    the_list = io.StringIO(list_keywords.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(the_list)
    ...# rest of program.....
    csv_file1 = pd.DataFrame(internal_linking_opportunities,
                                     columns=["Keyword", "Text", "Source URL", "Target URL", "Link Presence", "Keyword Position"])

si = io.StringIO()
cw = csv.writer(csv_file1)
output = make_response(si.getvalue())
output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"


return Response(render_template('index.html', output=output))
```

I have attempted to use other methods to return the CSV with no luck. Starting to think it could be due to the render_template function that I am using. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `render_template` is called `context` and can be used to provide the template with some variables for rendering. Adding a `Response` object to the templates context is not going to return that `Response`, but instead make that `Response` object accessible from within the template.

Flask has a dedicated method for sending files back to the browser:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file

Your return statement could look something like this:

```py
return send_file(file_pointer, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="export.csv")
```

Instead of providing the file pointer as the first argument, you can also use a file from your local disk by providing the path to that file. If you provide the file pointer, make sure to set it to the start of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am new to Flask and Python so your help is greatly appreciated. 

Since I also want to POST my  index.html file to the browser how can I accomplish both in the same return call? 

Or will I have to set the render template return in a separate Def function? 

Hopefully that makes sense and I am not being too confusing!

Comment: Yeah, you will need to add a separate view function / route. You can't both display a regular HTML page and initiate a download at the same time, at least from a technical point of view. You could utilize some JavaScript to get a similar user experience, though.